# Не подключаются стили в html файле когда запускаю посредством php

Tags: php, html, css

Скачал я бесплатный шаблон, добавил в свой проект. Пытаюсь запустить через PHP файл `index.html` из шаблона — запускается без стилей:

```
<?php 
require '/views/index.html';
```

Сам файл `index.html` ([он же на IDEOne](https://ideone.com/zqxYP9)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
Synchronous by TEMPLATED
templated.co @templatedco
Released for free under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license     (templated.co/license)
-->
<html>
<head>
 <title>Synchronous by TEMPLATED</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="description" content="" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="" />
 <link href='http://f...content-available-to-author-only...s.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
 <script src="http://a...content-available-to-author-only...s.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/init.js"></script>
 <noscript>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
 </noscript>
 <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
 <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v9.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="homepage">
 <div id="wrapper">
 
  <!-- Header -->
  <div id="header">
   <div class="container"> 
 
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div id="logo">
     <h1><a href="#">Synchronous</a></h1>
     <span>Design by TEMPLATED</span>
    </div>
 
    <!-- Nav -->
    <nav id="nav">
     <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
      <li><a href="threecolumn.html">Three Column</a></li>
      <li><a href="twocolumn1.html">Left Sidebar</a></li>
      <li><a href="twocolumn2.html">Right Sidebar</a></li>
      <li><a href="onecolumn.html">No Sidebar</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /Header -->
 
  <div id="page">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="3u">
      <section id="sidebar1">
       <header>
        <h2>Sidebar 1</h2>
       </header>
       <ul class="style3">
        <li class="first">
         <p class="date"><a href="#">Oct <b>03</b></a></p>
         <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent urna congue rutrum. </a></p>
        </li>
        <li>
         <p class="date"><a href="#">Sep <b>30</b></a></p>
         <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent urna congue rutrum.</a></p>
        </li>
        <li>
         <p class="date"><a href="#">Sep <b>27</b></a> </p>
         <p><a href="#">Donec leo, vivamus fermentum nibh in augue praesent urna congue rutrum.</a></p>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </section>
     </div>
     <div class="6u skel-cell-important">
      <section id="content" >
       <header>
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
       </header>
       <p>This is <strong>Synchronous</strong>, a responsive HTML5 site template freebie by <a href="http://t...content-available-to-author-only...d.co">TEMPLATED</a>. Released for free under the <a href="http://t...content-available-to-author-only...d.co/license">Creative Commons Attribution</a> license, so use it for whatever (personal or commercial) &ndash; just give us credit! Check out more of our stuff at <a href="http://t...content-available-to-author-only...d.co">our site</a> or follow us on <a href="http://t...content-available-to-author-only...r.com/templatedco">Twitter</a>.</p>
       <p>Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique ante ut risus. Quisque dictum. Integer nisl risus, sagittis convallis, rutrum id, elementum congue, nibh. Suspendisse dictum porta lectus. Donec placerat odio vel elit. Nullam ante orci, pellentesque eget, tempus quis, ultrices in, est. Curabitur sit amet nulla. Nam in massa. Sed vel tellus. Curabitur sem urna, consequat vel, suscipit in, mattis placerat, nulla. Sed ac leo.</p>
       <p>Sed etiam vestibulum velit mollis pretium suscipit, justo nulla blandit libero, in blandit augue justo quis nisl. Fusce mattis viverra elit. Fusce quis tortor. Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam pede erat, porta eu, lobortis eget lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
       <a href="#" class="button">Full Article</a>
      </section>
     </div>
     <div class="3u">
      <section id="sidebard2">
       <header>
        <h2>Sidebar 2</h2>
       </header>
       <ul class="style1">
        <li class="first"><span class="fa fa-check"></span><a href="#">Maecenas luctus lectus at sapien</a></li>
        <li><span class="fa fa-check"></span><a href="#">Etiam rhoncus volutpat erat</a></li>
        <li><span class="fa fa-check"></span><a href="#">Donec dictum metus in sapien</a></li>
        <li><span class="fa fa-check"></span><a href="#">Integer gravida nibh quis urna</a></li>
        <li><span class="fa fa-check"></span><a href="#">Etiam posuere augue sit amet nisl</a></li>
        <li><span class="fa fa-check"></span><a href="#">Mauris vulputate dolor nibh</a></li>
        <li><span class="fa fa-check"></span><a href="#">Nulla luctus eleifend purus</a></li>
       </ul>
       <a href="#" class="button">Full Article</a>
      </section>
     </div>
    </div>
 
   </div> 
  </div>
 
  <!-- Footer -->
  <div id="footer">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="3u">
      <section id="box1">
       <header>
        <h2>Nulla facilisi</h2>
       </header>
       <ul class="style3">
        <li class="first">
         <p class="date"><a href="#">10.03.2012</a></p>
         <p><a href="#">Vestibulum sem magna, elementum ut, vestibulum facilisis. Nulla facilisi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus.</a></p>
        </li>
        <li>
         <p class="date"><a href="#">10.03.2012</a></p>
         <p><a href="#">Pellentesque erat erat, tincidunt in, eleifend, malesuada bibendum. Suspendisse sit amet  in eros bibendum condimentum. </a> </p>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </section>
     </div>
     <div class="6u">
      <section id="box2">
       <header>
        <h2>Donec dictum metus</h2>
       </header>
       <div> <a href="#" class="image full"><img src="images/pics02.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
       <p>Nulla enim eros, porttitor eu, tempus id, varius non, nibh. Duis enim nulla, luctus eu, dapibus lacinia, venenatis id, quam. Vestibulum imperdiet, magna nec eleifend rutrum, nunc lectus vestibulum velit, euismod lacinia quam nisl id lorem. Quisque erat. Vestibulum pellentesque, justo mollis pretium suscipit, justo nulla blandit libero, in blandit augue justo quis nisl.</p>
      </section>
     </div>
     <div class="3u">
      <section id="box3">
       <header>
        <h2>Gravida ipsum</h2>
       </header>
       <ul class="style1">
        <li class="first"><a href="#">Pellentesque quis elit non lectus eleifend purus condimentum.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolort, consectetuer adipiscing dictum metus sapien.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Phasellus nec dictum metus in sapien pellentesque congue.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cras vitae metus aliquam risus dictum metus in sapien pharetra.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Duis non dictum metus in sapien ante in metus commodo euismod lobortis.</a></li>
       </ul>
      </section>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 
  <!-- Copyright -->
  <div id="copyright">
   <div class="container">
    Design: <a href="http://t...content-available-to-author-only...d.co">TEMPLATED</a> Images: <a href="http://u...content-available-to-author-only...h.com">Unsplash</a> (<a href="http://u...content-available-to-author-only...h.com/cc0">CC0</a>)
   </div>
  </div>
 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Запускаю HTML файл напрямую в том же браузере (Chrome) — стили работают. Я долго сидел и пытался понять в чем причина, но до меня никак не доходит — какая разница, вручную я открываю или это делает php. Оказывается разница есть, и во втором случае стили почему-то не подключаются.

Кто знает, почему?

Comment: в мануале написано, что работает не только с php, вы информацию с потолка взяли? да и даже если переименовать файл все равно стили не подключаются

Comment: http://www.php.su/require()   "Таким образом, конструкция require позволяет собирать сценарии PHP из нескольких отдельных файлов, которые могут быть как html-страницами, так и php-скриптами."               Пути правильно прописаны, запускается же когда я вручную запускаю этот файл

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  вот, что пишет в консоли

Comment: хмм, в `index.html` у вас все ссылки на стили и скрипты относительные, а файл `php` где лежит?

Comment: папке проекта, в корневой папке проекта, а index.html  и папки js css images в той же, что и index.html. Но причина не в этом, я вот заметил разницу, что когда запускаю сам, то в консоли нет ошибок, а когда запускаю через php, то что пишет                                             Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    skel-panels.min.js:1                                                Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <   init.js:1                     Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    skel.min.js:1

Comment: перенесите js, css, images в корневую папку рядом с index.php

Answer (score 2):

В консоли посмотрите все пути, и правильно ли они открывают файлы. В js тоже могут быть пути прописаны, возможно и там надо что-нибудь поменять

Answer (score -1):

В Chrome можно открыть консоль и посмотреть, правильно ли отдаются ссылки на *.css, — возможно, что путь к стилю прописывается неправильно при запуске скрипта. Измените путь к стилям относительно PHP-скрипта, сейчас он у вас прописан относительно HTML.